# Interested in making a 16-bit styled game in python

Tags: python, 2d, pygame, libraries

Recently I had a great idea for a 16-bit-styled 2D side-scrolling game I would like to make. I know C++ is the preferred language for game development, but I'm not too familiar with it and it seems like a hassle to learn. I'm much more comfortable using python and I rather get to work while it is fresh in my mind. I do have experience making some basic programs.

So my question is, what would are the best python gaming libraries or other tools to make a 2D side-scroller in a 16-bit style? Or, in other words, if I were trying to recreate a Super Nintendo game like Super Mario World, what would be the best way to go about doing that in python?

I've looked into Pygame, and while it does sound appealing, I haven't found any games made with it that really impressed me. I also heard of Pyglet, which seemed a little better to me, but I'm not too sure.

Thanks for the help. n__n

Comment: I've removed the 16-bit tag, because your actual program is certainly not going to be 16-bit.

Comment: Also, don't be surprised if this question ends up getting closed, because it's basically just asking for python game library recommendations.

Comment: Well I suppose, though I'm more interested in what library can most accurately create a retro styled game using python in terms of speed, functionality, and graphics, not just a recommendation.

Comment: I don't really think the "retro" aspect really puts any more requirements on the game library (in fact, it may be less).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to go with flash/actionscript for this, because you are looking for some libraries that will help you along the way? Pygame is amazing, but you will have to build everything by yourself, collision, blocks, scrolling,  and if you check pyagame.org you will find some amazing games built on top of pygame. You can find some libraries but they are not comprehensive and provide small things like collision only or only tile support.

Pyglet is less popular hence less games are made with it, and it has smaller community.

So my suggestion is learn actionscript 3, and use these libraries below they will speed your development a lot.

The most popular two are [flixel](http://flixel.org/) and [flashpunk](http://useflashpunk.net/).
They are both comprehensive and provide loads of features like tiles, collision (hit box), character animation, etc.

Comment: I haven't really considered flash/actionscript. This seems like it would work very well. I'll check it out. Thank you

Comment: You can read tutorials section on either of those websites they will provide info on how to set up the IDE and sdk and everything else, also check youtube.